# How to import large .csv file into mysql (+10gb)

Tags: mysql, csv, crash

i have a database in this format

```
CPF|Nome Completo|Sexo / Genero|Data de Nascimento
00000000272|Gherson Dywyno Esphyndola|M - Masculino|31/03/1966
00000000353|Paulo Ribeiro|M - Masculino|03/08/1942
00000000434|Jorge da Silveira|M - Masculino|04/04/1933
00000000515|Filomeno Gutierres Iglecia|M - Masculino|05/07/1910
```

[image: phpmyadmin]
i try use this but the mysql server crash

Comment: This is not a programming question. You can find better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a web-based gui operating within the constraints of a webserver. It does not have any means to run a long-running background process.

Comment: you should start by changing the line ending from auto to /r/n